# Less not compile viewport units (vmax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, bundling-and-minification, dotless

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 with LESS (bundle & dotless and LessTransform package). But less incorrectly compiles css viewport unit "vmax".

```
width: 20vmax;
```

and get output (vmax with space)

```
width: 20vm ax;
```

others viewport units (vh, vw, vmin) compiles correctly.

How to fix this error? 
Thanks

**UPD 28/08/2015**
I solved the problem as follows:

I removed less bundle

```
var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/less").Include("~/assets/css/responsive.less");
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```

and create new default styleBundle. I link compiled .css file, but not .less

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
                    "~/assets/css/responsive.css"));
```

and it works